# Write permission in home directory

Tags: permissions, root, home

Root doesn't have write permissions in my home directory, and every bin or sh file I want to run, needs to be run from root. My user has access to the files, but can't run them because its not root.

How do I enable write permissions to my home directory for the root?

EDIT:

```
ls -lad "$HOME" 
drwxr-xr-x+ 33 userid groupname 42 Aug  4 22:59 /home/userid
```

EDIT2: Output from getfacl /home/userid

```
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: home/userid
# owner: userid
# group: groupname
user::rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

EDIT 3: Output from df $HOME

```
Filesystem            1K-blocks       Used  Available Use% Mounted on
xxxxxxxx:/export/home1/userid
                     5156362272 3035249664 2121112608  59% /home/userid
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output from the two commands `id` and `ls -lad "$HOME"`. Ensure these are run as your own user account, not as root.

Comment: `+` sign indicates, it's protected with acl. do `getfacl /home/userid` and paste output on your question.

Comment: Thanks! How exactly do you give root user write permission on the home folder?

Comment: It says setfacl operation not supported :( and that I dont have access to /etc/fstab

Comment: What is the output of `df $HOME` ?

Comment: Try `mount -o remount,acl /home`

Comment: mount -o remount,acl /home gives can't find /home in /etc/fstab or etc/mtab

Comment: root *always* has write access to every filesystem that's writable in the first place. What error do you get when you try, and what are the exact attributes of the file you're trying to access?

Comment: I get Permission denied when I try to access a file with attributes -rwxr-xr-x+

Comment: that sound like NFS mount, which will ny default disable access for root. See `no_root_squash` option for your NFS export to fix it.